# Additional vent for Heating Boilers

Tags: vent, chimney

I have a very old house and I am renovating my basement and i recently bought a new 140k BTU boiler for heating. I have a separate boiler for hot water. Both boilers are being vented through a Chimney running all the way up through the roof. Do i need any additional vent in Boiler room if I am already venting through chimney?

Comment: What type of venting/exhaust system does your boiler use? (atmospheric draft, induced draft, direct vent, or power vent?)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the comment questions earlier. I have a brick chimney which is venting directly through the roof. There is no fan or anything pushing the gas through the chimney. I actually read a lot on subject matter and a lot of people suggests to have a fresh air vert installed in basement. This is to maintain fresh air and pressure inside of the home to prevent the backdraft.